# Simulating an actual page reload with Ember to enable Chrome password saving

Tags: google-chrome, ember.js, ember-cli

When a user submits our signup form in Safari and Firefox, they are prompted for saving their username and password. However, in Chrome this does not happen. After some research I have found that Chrome only prompts after an actual page refresh/redirect after login which I achieve using document.location = "/". However, this causes an unnecessary page reload and flicker. Any suggestions on how I can work around this Chrome limitation for single page apps would be appreciated please.